# Where is the webkit_debug log located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara-webkit

I am working on transitioning from the default rack_test driver to the webkit driver so I can run javascript in my rspec tests. Unfortunately, I am getting session timeout errors, so I changed my driver to webkit_debug, however, I can't seem to find the webkit_debug log file for the life of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, capybara-webkit prints directly to standard error.

More specifically:

The driver consists of two components: a Ruby adapter which conforms to the Capybara API, and a server process (written in C++) which implements a fake WebKit browser.

When logging is enabled, the C++ process prints entries to stderr using [qCritical](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qCritical). The Ruby driver copies the server's stderr to its output target, which is Ruby's `$stderr` by default.

You can have capybara-webkit write to another IO object by passing it as `stderr` when initializing the driver.